# Чтобы select считал и разрешал не более одной записи в бд

Tags: php, mysqli

```php
$r = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE id='".$id."' AND site !='' AND site='".$site."'") or die(mysqli_connect_error());
$nr = mysqli_num_rows($r);
if($nr>0) $err = $err."Запись уже существует<br>";
```

Здравствуйте, как подправить код? Нужно что бы допускалась только одна запись в столбце сити, если запись уже есть, писал ошибку.

Comment: Ваша проблема не совсем понятна.  `SELECT COUNT(*)` без группировки по другим полям и так вернет только одну строку с указанием числа совпадений, и нужно будет проверить число, которое возвращается таким запросом.  Если вы ищете по какому-то ключевому полю `id` с дополнительным условием по `site` **БЕЗ аггрегирующих функций** -- у вас и так может вернуться 0 или максимум 1 строка.  Ваш способ формирования запроса небезопасен, так как позволяет провести SQL-инъекцию.

Comment: Спасибо Nowhere Man, вроде бы и простой запрос, но не получается, пользователю нужно ввести данные, если запись уже есть, должен писать ошибку. Подобных примеров не могу найти.

Comment: Предварительно через `php` запросить город с таким названием, если результат пустой - то записать. Либо сделать столбец город `unique` в mysql, но тогда надо при попытке записи получать `exception` через `try/catch`, также можно сделать [on duplicate key update](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html), но тут он не уместен